# Is there a way to simply transpose data in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm a newbie to SAS.  I am trying to document the table structure of the 50+ data sets and so I want to just take the top 5 rows from each data set and output it on console.  However, since many of these data sets have many columns I would like to transpose them.  I tried to use proc transpose but apparently it doesn't just flip the results and keeps dropping columns.

For example, the following code only produce results with MSGID and LINENO only...

```
proc print data=sashelp.smemsg;
run;

proc transpose data=sashelp.smemsg out=work.test;
run;

proc print data=work.test;
run;
```

*Update*:
I think it didn't work because SAS doesn't know how to "normalize" the data types after the transformation.  I would like to something similar to this in R where all numbers became string.

```
> df <- data.frame(x=11:20, y=letters[1:10])
> df
    x y
1  11 a
2  12 b
3  13 c
4  14 d
5  15 e
6  16 f
7  17 g
8  18 h
9  19 i
10 20 j
> t(df)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
x "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" 
y "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"  "i"  "j"
```

Comment: You need to use by/id/var statements to get the desired result. Using your sashelp.smemsg example, what do you want the output dataset to look like?

Comment: I just want to rotate the table in the output.  I think I can guess why it didn't work.  The columns in the original table are of different data types so SAS is unable to create another data set because the content of each column will contain multiple data types.

Comment: What kind of output do you need? Would a text, PDF or Word document be okay? If so, I recommend Call VNEXT

Comment: Transposing and printing data sets seems like an inefficient way to go when you can simply look at the data set contents via the Viewtable command (which can be abbreviated as vt). You can also see the list of variables and variable types by right-clicking on the data set in Explorer and selecting View Columns.

Comment: Another easy simple way to "document the table structure of the 50+ data sets" is to use PROC CONTENTS and this produces a list of all variable names and whether or not they are character or numeric, plus other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

To quickly look at the data in SAS dataset I normally just use a PUT statement and look at the log.

```
data _null_;
  set have (obs=5);
  put (_all_) (=/);
run;
```

If you just want to transpose the data then use PROC TRANSPOSE.  You need to specify the variables or you will only get the numeric ones.

```
proc transpose data=have (obs=5) out=want ;
   var _all_ ;
run;
proc print data=want ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is roughly how to do it.

### Generate sample dataset having 25 rows, 6 numeric vars and 6 string vars

```
data sample;
  array num_col_(6);
  array str_col_(6) $;
  do row_number = 1 to 25;
    do col_number = 1 to 6;
      num_col_(col_number) = round(ranuni(0),.01);
      str_col_(col_number) = byte(ceil(ranuni(0)*10)+97);
    end;
    output;
  end;
  drop row_number col_number;
run;
```

### Transpose data, keeping only 5 first rows

```
proc transpose data=sample(obs=5) prefix=row
               out=sample_tr(rename=(_name_=column));
  var num_col_: str_col_:;
  /* You could also use keywords on the var statement */
  * var _character_ _numeric_; * Lets you decide which type to show first;
  * var _all_; * Keeps original order of variables;
run;
```

### Show the results

```
proc print data=sample_tr noobs;
  id column;
  var row1-row5;
run;
```

### Results

```
column      row1  row2  row3  row4  row5 
---------   ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
num_col_1   0.66  0.96  0.85  0.45  0.32 
num_col_2   0.78  0.79  0.64  0.85  0.74 
num_col_3   0.23  0.62  0.46  0.46  0.51 
num_col_4   0.91  0.15  0.16  0.77  0.13 
num_col_5   0.6   0.48  0.32  0.6   0.77 
num_col_6   0.13  0.76  0.67  0.16  0.67 
str_col_1   c     i     i     i     c 
str_col_2   j     k     f     f     c 
str_col_3   e     g     k     h     i 
str_col_4   b     h     d     k     e 
str_col_5   c     h     f     e     f 
str_col_6   i     b     k     i     f
```

Comment: PROC TRANSPOSE will convert the variables to strings for you if you have mixed types.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks.